# Setting jQuery UI Tab Duration/Time on a Per Tab Basis

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

How would I set the 'impression' or time the slide/tab is display on a per tab basis?

I have all the content pulling from a database and am setting the 'itemid' on each  to the database value time to display.  I'm using the jquery-ui-tabs-rotate.js and utilizing the .tabs('rotate') function.

Main script initializing the content rotation:

```
    $("#featured").tabs({
    fx: [{ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle', duration: 'slow' },
         { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 'fast' }],
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var $panel = $(ui.panel);

        if ($panel.is(":empty")) {
            var tabID = "#ui-tabs-" + (ui.index + 1);
            $(tabID).html("<b>Fetching Data.... Please wait....</b>");
        }
    }
}).tabs('rotate', 2000, true);
```

Attempt to set duration per slide here:

```
    /* logic here to determine duration of tab */
$("#featured").bind("tabsselected", function (event, ui) {
    $(this).tabs({
        fx: [{ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle', duration: 'slow' },
             { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 'fast' }],
    }).tabs('rotate', $('#nav-fragment-' + (ui.index + 1)).attr('itemid'), true)
});
```

Comment: Changing the duration param won't have an effect unless you re-initialize tabs(). You'll probably have to not use the rotate function and instead build your own with your specific values.

Comment: Thanks @isherwood I suspected that.